# How to determine which PER file is loaded in the current session of Trace-32

Tags: trace32

In a running Trace-32 Debugging Session, can you please tell me how to determine the currently loaded PER file name using some commands?
Thank you.
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file shown by the PER or PER.view command is (when no explicit filename is used)

- the last file used with the command PER.ReProgram
- the last file for which the "Compile" button was pressed in the PER.Program editor
- the default-peripheral file for the selected CPU if the two above
  haven't happened

In any case you can see the name of the file shown by PER or PER.view (when no explicit filename is used) in the window VERSION.Software.

The VERSION.Software window does not refresh automatically. So re-open the window, to get the latest results.